# Project Tango, camera position?

Tags: google-project-tango

I would like to be able to take a photo indoors and be able to determine the position (x,y,z coordinates) of the camera in the room. Is this/will this be possible with Project Tango and the Lenovo Phab 2 Pro phone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you made an app yourself you could use an ADF (Area Description File) to determine the devices position relative to where you started to record the ADF. You can get position as XYZ and rotation as a quaternion.

Worth noting is that the camera on the Project Tango Tablet DK has a really bad camera, so it really wouldnt be worth the effort with that, although the Phab 2 Pro probably has a better camera.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Axel. I'm new to creating apps - will have to do some more Googling!